# Syntax Highlighting with Line Numbers in Jekyll and Github Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, syntax-highlighting

I used Github Pages to host my personal website and I am trying to create a post which contains code snippets with line numbers.

When I do a jekyll serve on my machine, locally I can see everything working as expected, viz.,

[image]

However, when I push it to my Github repo and try to view the site live, the line numbering breaks. I see the following

[image]

[image]

I am using code fences to specify the code, like so,

````
~```python"
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns
.set_style("darkgrid")
~```
````

I have also tried the liquid syntax `{% highlight python linenos %} . . . {% endhighlight %}` but the problem persists.

My `_config.yml` has the following settings

```
# Conversion
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
lsi: false
excerpt_separator: "\n\n"
incremental: false


# Markdown Processing
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  hard_wrap: false
  auto_ids: true
  footnote_nr: 1
  entity_output: as_char
  toc_levels: 1..6
  smart_quotes: lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo
  enable_coderay: false
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    block:
      line_numbers: true
# HTML Compression
# - http://jch.penibelst.de/
compress_html:
  clippings: all
  ignore:
    envs: development
```

and the css/scss file can be found [here](https://github.com/subhodeeps/subhodeeps.github.io/blob/master/_sass/_syntax.scss).

I can't understand the reason behind this discrepancy and how can I solve it?

**Edit:** I tried commenting out the HTML compression portion in `_config.yml` and I can then see the same error locally.

Comment: Have you tried disabling HTML compression (the `compress_html` setting)? It can mess up things like that. Your production HTML nests `<class>` tags incorrectly somehow.

Comment: You are probably right: I commented out the relevant portion and saw that locally I get the same incorrect result. I am not sure how to change it. I am adding it to the question.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I set `envs: [development, production]`, and apparently fixed the issue. I am unsure it that is breaking anything else atm.

Comment: I believe if you drop the entire `compress_html` object, it won't be compressed anywhere.